# When I run the animate function nothing happens, what can I do to fix this?

Tags: javascript, smartface.io

Here is a sample of my code, despite the duration it instantly alerts me that the Animate is Complete. Please help me, do I need to import a package. Is it the duration that is not working. It kinda just jumps to the end value.

```
rectangle1 = new SMF.UI.Rectangle({
        left : "20%",
        top : "10%",
        width : "60%",
        height : "20%",
        fillColor : "#FF00FF"
    });
page1.add(rectangle1);
rectangle1.animate({
    property : 'top',
    endValue : "30%",
    motionEase : SMF.UI.MotionEase.BOUNCE,
    duration : 3000,
    onFinish : function () {
        alert("Animate Completed");
    }
});
```

Comment: anything interesting in the browsers **developer** tools console

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: you are developing a web page?

Comment: No, its an IOS app. I am developing it through the smartface.io ide

Comment: oh ... wait ... didn't see the `smartface.io` tag ... sorry, thought this would be easily debugged in a browser

Comment: Yeah no problem, I appreciate you offering me your time anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make animation after pageshow event fired.
For example:

```
function page1_onShow() {

    setTimeout(animate,100)
}

function animate()
{
    rectangle1.animate({
        property : 'top',
        endValue : "30%",
        motionEase : SMF.UI.MotionEase.BOUNCE,
        duration : 3000,
        onFinish : function () {
            alert("Animate Completed");
        }
    });
}
```